# How do I iterate through the JSON structure to access the first date in the structure?

Tags: json, swift, loops

Here is my JSON:

```
{
    "col": {

        "2021-02-14": [
            {
                "name": "green",
                "size": "large",
            },
            {
                "name": "grey",
                "size": "small",
            },
            {
                "name": "blue",
                "size": "small",
            }
        ],

        "2021-02-21": [
            {
                "name": "grey",
                "size": "large",
            },
            {
                "name": "grey",
                "size": "small",
            }
        ]

    }
}
```

The date for example "2021-02-14" is a dynamic key, that's why I try to use the For-In Loops to access it. I managed to write the code which loops through the whole structure but returns the dates randomly, sometimes "2021-02-14" is printed first, sometimes "2021-02-14" is first. I know that dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations but is there a way around it? My code below:

```
func parseMyJSON() {
    
    if let dates = try? JSON(data: data) {
        
        let col = dates["col"]
        
        for (key, subJson) in col {
            print(key)
            for (_, subJson) in subJson {
                print(subJson["name"], subJson["size"], subJson["image"])
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
2021-02-21
grey large 
grey small 
2021-02-14
green large 
grey small 
blue small
```

thank you

Comment: Forget about using SwiftyJSON. Take a look at Codable protocol (Swift 4 or later)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Get the dictionary for key `col`
- Sort the keys
- Get the value for the first key and iterate the array

---

```
if let dates = try? JSON(data: data),
   let col = dates["col"].dictionary,
   let firstKey = col.keys.sorted().first {

      for subJson in col[firstKey]!.arrayValue {
          print(subJson["name"], subJson["size"], subJson["image"])
      }
   }
}
```

Side note: Since Swift 4 `SwiftyJSON` has become obsolete in favor of the `Codable` protocol.

Comment: no need to sort the whole collection if OP is only looking for the first date

Comment: This is not what I meant `if let key = col.keys.min()`. No need to sort them.